# How to setup custom jupyter kernels on WSL2?

Tags: virtualenv, windows-subsystem-for-linux, jupyter-kernel

I've been following https://queirozf.com/entries/jupyter-kernels-how-to-add-change-remove to create a jupyter kernel.

This procedure worked when I was on Ubuntu or WSL1.

However, I'm unable to change kernel on WSL2. Whatever custom kernel I select, the python and pip-packages seem to be pointing to the version where the jupyter notebook is launched and not the virtualenv associated to the kernel.

Does anyone know how to setup custom jupyter kernels on WSL2 ?

Answer (score 0):

The recent update on my computer seemed to have resolved the problem